# How to convert webpack with es6 to general react

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a webpack react project. It runs only webpack, but I want to remove the webpack related matter and run as a normal react project.

Comment: can you help by defining what a "normal react project" looks like for you?

Comment: normal react project means without  using web pack

Comment: i shared the link https://github.com/Raathigesh/Dazzle.This includes the webpack related stuff.I just want to remove the web pack.what are the changes required if i changed to web pack to without webpack in react

Comment: Link https://github.com/Raathigesh/Dazzle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

webpack is just a bundler. It bundles all your js files and dump that as string in eval function in one single js file.

I Got your question now. I guess, you mean that you have a react project. Its developed now. And you want only the usefule files now, right? If thats the case, you need only two files(primarily for the project). First you build the project with whatever script you have, I guess, **npm run build**.

Post that, you will see a dist folder at the root.
Inside that dist folder you will find one **index.html** file and **index.js** file. Besides this you may want css and assets folder.

Does that answers your concern?

Comment: I know the definition of web pack,i just want to change webpack to without web pack. i shared the link https://github.com/Raathigesh/Dazzle.This includes the webpack related stuff.I just want to remove the web pack.what are the changes required if i changed to web pack to without webpack in react

Comment: Hi @AlluManikyam, The page you mentioned throws 404, Doesn't look correct link. Please check.

Comment: Thank you Aditya,Yes that is my problem.could you please tell me the steps briefly  about that process